# CSS for Google AdSense Responsive Ad on ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, adsense

I just realized that due to bad implementation of my `AdSense` responsive ad the ads were not displaying correctly for quite a while on my `Bootstrap` website.

I have now changed the HTML/CSS as such:

```
<div class="adsense-responsive">
    <style type="text/css">
        .adslot_1 {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 15px 0px;
        }
        @@media (min-width:100px) {
            .adslot_1 {
                width: 125px;
                height: 125px;
            }
        }
        @@media (min-width:180px) {
            .adslot_1 {
                width: 180px;
                height: 150px;
            }
        }
        @@media (min-width:200px) {
            .adslot_1 {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        }
        @@media (min-width:250px) {
            .adslot_1 {
                width: 250px;
                height: 250px;
            }
        }
        @@media (min-width:300px) {
            .adslot_1 {
                width: 300px;
                height: 600px;
            }
        }
        @@media (min-width:336px) {
            .adslot_1 {
                width: 336px;
                height: 280px;
            }
        }
        @@media (min-width:468px) {
            .adslot_1 {
                width: 468px;
                height: 60px;
            }
        }
        @@media (min-width:728px) {
            .adslot_1 {
                width: 728px;
                height: 90px;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

    <ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
         style="display: inline-block;"
         data-ad-client="xx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx">
    </ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>        
</div>
```

The CSS is inline as that's what was suggested in the documentation.
Apart from these, the only additional CSS I have is on the parent container `.adsense-responsive` to make the ads centered:

```
.adsense-responsive {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This seems to work ok but I occasionally notice some bugs (for example, the ad seems to overflow it's container on portrait mode on Chrome on the Galaxy Note 4. Is this due to bad implementation on my side? I'm also not entirely sure if my declaration of the default values for `.adslot_1` are correct (whether `max-width` should be `width` and whether it should pe in `px` rather than `%`)

EDIT: Added `ASP.NET MVC` in the title to avoid confusion around `@@media` (`Razor` syntax)

Comment: What browser are you using on Galaxy Note 4. Edit your question to add this information.

Comment: That would be Chrome. I have updated the question, thanks.